# What are ordered hashes in Ruby used for?

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I recently started learning Ruby and hashes. At first I learned that hashes are unordered which makes sense, but now I found out that hashes are ordered with later versions of Ruby. I don't really understand why or the concept behind this.

Could I get some insight as to what the ordered hashes are for? Possible use cases would be nice too for regular hash vs. ordered hash.

Comment: Sometimes insertion order matters, it's basically an automatic queue, but with the addition of key lookup. The difference in use cases is obvious, "when insertion order matters". Note, however, that they may not be "for" anything, rather it's an implementation detail.

Comment: It's important to know that a lot of languages offer this functionality, but I think you should never rely on it, especially if your code will have to run on older versions of Ruby, or will be ported to run on other languages. It's easy to program the same behavior.

Comment: Why would order matter for arrays? What do you mean by "regular hash"?

Comment: insertion order was implemented in 1.9 and actually seems to have improved the performance of a Hash for both insert and access operations. I say seems to have because the 1.9 interpreter is faster than 1.8.7 so it is hard to determine how much of this can be attributed to the ordered Hash and how much is directly the interpreter

Answer (score 4):

Some people like to rely on ordering of a Hash, because the ordered-hash remembers the insertion order of the key/value pairs. This allows the programmer to use a hash somewhat like a queue with random access to the values associated with the keys. This would be useful if they intend to change values on the fly and then iterate over the queue's key/value pairs to retrieve them in the insertion order again.

Also, rather than have to supply indexes into the queue, like they would if they were using an Array-based queue, they can supply a symbolic name.

Instead of:

```
queue[0]
```

they can use:

```
queue[:fred]
```

That's the only use-case I can see for ordered hashes; It'd be really easy to duplicate the functionality with a queue of keys that preserved the insertion order.

Answer (score 3):

Looking back at some of the previous posts by Matz, he was pretty vague as to why it was implemented. Check out https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/166075

He basically states that it was implemented to fit some edge cases but he didn't seem to elaborate on it more than that. He also stated that there was no impact on performance, just a negligible increase in memory consumption.

Comment: In the very first comment on that thread Matz clearly said: it was done to ease handling of 2.0 keywords arguments. Imagine: `def f a: 42, **args` called as `f(x: true, a: 0, y: false)`. `Enumerator` got [`peek`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) and family, `Hash` just derived the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine git commits, handled by ruby git wrapper. They are likely instance of a `Hash`, with `sha` as keys. While the sorting by `Date` makes them easily iteratable in a human-friendly manner.